# AJAX GET запрос news.php?del=$id

Tags: php, ajax

Знаю без ajax выполнить запрос а как с ajax это сделать?

HTML
`<form method="GET">`
`<a href="news.php?del=$id">Удалить</a>`
`</form>`

PHP
`if(isset($_GET['del']))
{
...
}`

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите удалять новости без перезагрузки страницы. Давайте попробуем. Для начала каждой кнопке `Удалить` добавим идентификатор, по которому мы будем отслеживать нажатие, использовать будем класс (произвольное имя), ведь мы всегда помним, что нельзя размещать на одной странице несколько элементов с одинаковым идентификатором `id`, + добавим атрибут `data-id` к каждой кнопке, чтобы `js` знал, какую новость мы хотим удалить, + пусть каждая новость у нас будет в `div` с идентификатором `news<?php echo $id; ?>`, чтобы после удаления скрывать её или менять содержимое к примеру, да что угодно:

```
<div id="news<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <p>
        Я хорошая или плохая новость
    </p>
    <button class="delete-news" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>">Удалить меня</button>
</div>
```

Далее `js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.delete-news').click(function(){    // обработчик события
        var newsId = jQuery(this).data('id');    // читаем атрибут data-id у нажатой кнопки, чтобы знать, что мы удаляем
        jQuery.ajax({    // выполняем запрос к скрипту news.php
            url: '/news.php',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {id: newsId},    // отправляем POST данные - ID нужной новости, в news.php принимаем их так: $id =  $_POST['id']
            error: function(){    // это на случай, если что-то пойдёт не так
                alert('Что-то пошло не так!');
            },
            success: function(data){    // а это если всё идёт как запланировано
                // далее можно делать что хотите, обновить DOM новости либо скрыть её - выберите что-то одно
                jQuery('#news' + newsId).html(data); // меняем содержимое div удалённой новости на то, что прислал нам обработчик news.php в eсho
                jQuery('#news' + newsId).fadeOut(3000);    // либо скрываем её в неизвестность за 3 секунды
                jQuery('#news' + newsId).html(data + '<br />Я новость номер ' + newsId + ' и меня только что удалили, я пропаду насовсем через 10 секунд, не забывайте меня!').fadeOut(10000);    // либо совместим всё в кашу
            }

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Далее в `news.php` принимаем `ID` новости, удаляем её и возвращаем ответ:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
/**
 * здесь тусуется ваш код удаления, где вы с $id делаете фокусы
 */
$data = 'Я новость №' . $id . '. Наверное я очень плохая новость, раз меня удалили =(';
echo $data; // это и будет самая загадочная переменная data в js, вообще-то её можно назвать как душе угодно
exit();    // выходим, если в вашем файле news.php есть что-то ещё, кроме функции удаления новости
```

Ну и не забываем подключить [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Comment: Получаю ответ "Что-то пошло не так!"

Comment: `<?php
$id = 1;
?>
<div id="news<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <p>
        Я хорошая или плохая новость
    </p>
    <button class="delete-news" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>">Удалить меня</button>
</div>`

Comment: @Sauron значит ajax запрос не отправляется, скорее всего неправильный `url` попробуй так: `url: <?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>/news.php` ну или где у тебя лежит news.php?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX запрос с помощью [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    var id= $("#id").val();
    $.get('news.php', {del:id}, function(data){
    // обработка ответа
   });
  });
});
```

Comment: Можете точнее. html <a href="">перенаправит на другую страницу Новости сперва тяну через While () Там далее должны кнопки удалить изменить но как это сделать на ajax ...